# Magento 2 - Controller returning blank page

Tags: php, magento2

Been spending the last 1 day to find a fix for this.

Basically everything works normal if I delete all the contents of generated folder and then generate the files dynamically by accessing the pages rather than doing setup:di:compile.

On the production though, I'm forced to do setup:di:compile and I end up with this certain admin module page being empty.

This is the controller of the page:

```
namespace Eadesigndev\AWB\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Eadesigndev\Awb\Api\AwbRepositoryInterface;
use Eadesigndev\Awb\Model\Awb;
use Eadesigndev\Awb\Model\AwbFactory;
use Eadesigndev\Awb\Helper\Data as DataHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Edit extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     *
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Eadesigndev_Awb::awb';

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    private $awbRepository;

    private $awbFactory;

    private $registry;

    private $session;

    private $dataHelper;

    private $awbModel;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        AwbRepositoryInterface $awbRepository,
        AwbFactory $awbFactory,
        Awb $awbModel,
        Registry $registry,
        DataHelper $dataHelper
    ) {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->awbRepository     = $awbRepository;
        $this->awbFactory        = $awbFactory;
        $this->registry          = $registry;
        $this->awbModel          = $awbModel;
        $this->session           = $context->getSession();
        $this->dataHelper        = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Edit action new awb.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        if ($id) {
              $model = $this->awbRepository->getById($id);
            if (!$model->getEntityId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This field no longer exists.'));
                /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create();
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        } else {
            echo '3';
            $model = $this->awbFactory->create();
        }

        /** @var Session $data */
        $data = $this->session->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        $this->registry->register('awb_data', $model);

        echo 'wat';
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Edit new Awb'), __('Edit new Awb'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Edit new Awb'));

        echo 'pac';
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

the controller currently returns a blank page with my debug strings:

```
3watpac
```

in `/vendor/eadesignro/awb/Block/Adminhtml/Xtea` I have the next files:

```
Edit    (folder)
Edit.php
EditAwb.php
```

in `/vendor/eadesignro/awb/view/adminhtml/layout` I have the next files:

```
shipping_awb_index_edit.xml
shipping_awb_index_editawb.xml
shipping_awb_index_index.xml
```

Content of `shipping_awb_index_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Eadesigndev\Awb\Block\Adminhtml\Xtea\Edit" name="awb_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Eadesigndev\Awb\Block\Adminhtml\Xtea\Edit\Tabs" name="awb_edit_tabs">
                <block class="Eadesigndev\Awb\Block\Adminhtml\Xtea\Edit\Tab\General" name="awb_edit_tab_general"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">general_section</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">awb_edit_tab_general</argument>
                </action>

                <block class="Eadesigndev\Awb\Block\Adminhtml\Xtea\Edit\Tab\Curier" name="awb_edit_tab_curier"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">curier_section</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">awb_edit_tab_curier</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is the page:
magento_admin_secreturl/shipping_awb/index/edit/key/xxxxxx

these are the routers:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
 <router id="admin">
     <route id="shipping_awb" frontName="shipping_awb">
         <module name="Eadesigndev_Awb" before="Magento_Backend"/>
     </route>
     <route id="edit_awb" frontName="edit_awb">
         <module name="Eadesigndev_Awb" before="Magento_Backend"/>
     </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

Any possible idea on why `$this->resultPageFactory->create();` is simply returning nothing on production but working on development?
The index page works both on production and dev without any problem.

I can provide more info if needed, thank you!

Comment: What's your patch of routes.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a CAPSLOCK mistake in the namespace.

```
namespace Eadesigndev\AWB\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
```

should have been

```
 namespace Eadesigndev\Awb\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
```

notice the 'AWB' becoming 'Awb'.

Apparently in development mode, the namespaces are not case-sensitive? or perhaps they are  all transformed to capslock. If anyone has a clue, leave a comment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still getting a blank page in Admin Controller, but the alternative solutions (*case-sensitive*) doesn't work for you, you may try running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

This helped me.